# Database Retrieval to Session Variable Storage

Tags: php, session-variables

PHP 7 and MySQL. I want to take a set of labels stored in the database and individually place each label in its own session variable so I can use them as tab labels in my application.

I can retrieve the data and echo it but the corresponding session variables all show a not set status.

```
<?php

require_once('dbconnect.inc.php');

$_SESSION['histopic'] = "dash";

$numnames = 100;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $numnames; $i++) {

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT hislabelsName FROM hislabels WHERE hislabelsID = ?');

    $temp = $i;

    $stmt->execute(array($temp));
    $result = $stmt->fetchALL();

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $_SESSION['hislabelsName$i'] = $row["hislabelsName"];
    }

    echo $_SESSION['hislabelsName$i'] . "<br>";
    echo $_SESSION['hislabelsName5'] . "<br>";
}
```

`echo $_SESSION['hislabelsName5'];` produces an undefined index error.

How do I fix this?

TIA.

Comment: Try using double quotes instead of single quotes; for example $_SESSION["hislabelsName$i"]

Comment: @thepieterdc is right. Single quotes support only strings to be wrapped inside it and variable values can't be parsed.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. It works now!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use double quotes like this:

```
$_SESSION["hislabelsName$i"] = $row["hislabelsName"];
```

You also do it like this:

```
$_SESSION["historylabelsName][$i] = $row["hislabelsName"];
```

Then to echo either:

`echo $_SESSION["hislabelsName5"]` or `echo $_SESSION["hislabelsName][5];`